# "Undefined Index" error after form has been submitted

Tags: php, mysql

in this page I have a form and I have $_GET values from the previous page.

```
$event_id = $_GET["event_id"];
$event_host_id = $_GET["event_user_id"];
$host_username = $_GET["username"];
$event_name = $_GET["event_name"];
$sport = $_GET["sport"];
$description = $_GET["description"];
$location = $_GET["location"];
$event_date = $_GET["event_date"];
$formatted_event_date = date("D jS F Y g:i a", strtotime($event_date));
$number_of_tickets = $_GET["number_of_tickets"];
$tick_end_date = $_GET["tick_end_date"];
$formatted_t_e_d = date("D jS F Y g:i a", strtotime($tick_end_date));
$tickets_remaining = $_GET["tickets_remaining"];
```

The page loads fine, with the GET variables being used without problem.
However, when I submit my form:

```
<form  action="give_feedback.php" method="POST">
    Rating<input name="rating" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0 /10</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showValue(newValue) {
            document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue + " /10";
        }
    </script><br><br>
    <textarea name="comment" rows="4" cols="30" selectionStart spellcheck="true" placeholder="Feedback comment"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit_feedback" name="submit_feedback" />
</form>
```

using :

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_feedback"])) {
    if(true) {
        //DO FORM VERIFICATION HERE
        $rating = (int)($_POST["rating"]);
        $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["comment"]);

        $query = "UPDATE `booking_dates` SET `rating` = '$rating', `comment` = '$comment' WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND `event_id` = '$event_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        check_query_result($result);
    }
}
```

There is an Undefined index error for all of the GET variables that were perfectly fine before and therefore my query is unable to send.
Here is the full code of the give_feedback.php file:

```
<?php 
require('includes/session.php');
require('includes/connect.php');
require('includes/functions.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="stylesheets/layout.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <title>My account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Holder">
            <div>
                <img class="logo" src="images/sports%20world%20logo.png" width="400px" height="200px">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="logged_in">Logged in as <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION["username"]); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div id="NavBar">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="LoggedInIndex.php">All Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="create_event.php">Create Event</a></li>
                        <li class="selected"><a href="my_account.php">My account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="event_ratings.php">Event Ratings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="log_out.php">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="Content">
                <div id="PageHeading">
                    <h1 id="Header">Give feedback on this event:</h1>
                </div>
                <?php
                $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
                if(isset($_GET["event_id"])){
                    $event_id = $_GET["event_id"];
                }
                if(isset($_GET["event_user_id"])){
                    $event_host_id = $_GET["event_user_id"];
                }
                if(isset($_GET["username"])){
                    $host_username = $_GET["username"];
                }
                if(isset($_GET["event_name"])){
                    $event_name = $_GET["event_name"];
                }
                if(isset($_GET["sport"])){
                    $sport = $_GET["sport"];
                }
                if(isset($_GET["description"])){
                    $description = $_GET["description"];
                }
                if(isset($_GET["location"])){
                    $location = $_GET["location"];
                }
                if(isset($_GET["event_date"])){
                    $event_date = $_GET["event_date"];
                }
                $formatted_event_date = date("D jS F Y g:i a", strtotime($event_date));
                ?>

                <div class="boxed">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h3><u><?php echo $event_id; ?></u></h3>
                        <h3><u><?php echo $event_name; ?></u></h3>
                        <h4>Hosted By <?php echo $host_username; ?></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>

                        <h5><a href="my_account.php">Back To My Events</a></h5>

                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="table_left">Sport</td>
                                <td class="table_right"><?php echo $sport; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="table_left">Location</td>
                                <td class="table_right"><?php echo $location; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="table_left">Date</td>
                                <td class="table_right"><?php echo $formatted_event_date; ?></td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <h2>Your feedback:</h2>
                    <form  action="give_feedback.php" method="POST">
                        Rating<input name="rating" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
                        <span id="range">0 /10</span>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function showValue(newValue)
                            {
                                document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue + " /10";
                            }
                        </script><br><br>
                        <textarea name="comment" rows="4" cols="30" selectionStart spellcheck="true" placeholder="Feedback comment"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit_feedback" name="submit_feedback" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php    
if(isset($_POST["submit_feedback"])){
    if(true){//DO FORM VERIFICATION HERE
        $rating = (int)($_POST["rating"]);
        $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["comment"]);

        echo $rating;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $comment;

        $query = "UPDATE `booking_dates` SET `rating` = '$rating', `comment` = '$comment' WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND `event_id` = '$event_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        check_query_result($result);
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: where are the input fields in the form for the php to get? i also note you are POSTing the form but GETting in php. you should be using post throughout or modify the code to use get throughout.

Comment: @Chris I changed my form to GET but the same issue still occurs. My form  input fields are  a text box and a slider

Comment: Okay that explains why they dont show in your code, you changed the post in the if block too?

Comment: change the value of your action on the form to `<form method="POST" action="<? echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">`.  This will pass along all of your `GET` values.

Comment: alternatively, you could add them as hidden inputs of the form so they get posted: `    <?php // add all GET vars as inputs to post
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $val . '">';
    } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

when you submitting the form the $GET values from the previous form will not passing. You can avoid the error by adding if(isset()) condition to every $GET variable.

```
      if(isset($_GET["event_id"])){ $event_id = $_GET["event_id"]; }
      if(isset($_GET["event_user_id"])){  $event_host_id = $_GET["event_user_id"]; }
        .
       ..


       ..

        .

        .

        .
        if(isset($_GET["tickets_remaining"])){ $tickets_remaining = $_GET["tickets_remaining"]; }
```

OR

pass all get values to the submitted form.

Comment: I have added isset to every get variable but now I get "undefined variable" errors...

Comment: What do you mean by pass all get values to the submitted form?

Comment: If you need all those variables ($event_id,$event_host_id , etc.. ) after form submit , then you have to pass all those values to the next form.

Comment: can you please show full code in give_feedback.php file?

Comment: The issue is, when you submitting the feedback form, the $GET variables passed from the previous page will be lost. You can fix this issue by 1) storing all $GET variables passed from the first form to session (ie: if(isset($_GET["event_id"])){
                    $_SESSION['event_id'] = $_GET["event_id"];
                })  and use $_SESSION['event_id']  instead of $event_id

Comment: second option is pass $event_id value on form submit      <form  action="give_feedback.php?event_id=<?php echo $event_id; ?>" method="POST"> and redirect to success page after successful submission of the form

Answer (score 0):

Check your database tables including data types and length of each specific data type.